# how to send email in android eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-asynctask

```
private class RetriveTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
    @Override
     protected void onPreExecute() {
        prop = new Properties();
        prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");



        session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password);
                    }
                }); 
    };
     @Override
     protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
         try{
             Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
             message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("dev.montaser@gmail.com"));
             message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                     InternetAddress.parse("eng.montaser99@yahoo.com"));
             message.setSubject("Test JCG Example");
             message.setContent("Hello how are you","text/html; charset=utf-8");

             Transport.send(message);

         } catch (AddressException e) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Problem in addree",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         } catch (MessagingException e) {
             Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Problem in message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         }
         return null;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute(Void s) {
         Toast.makeText(context,"Message send",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     }
 }
```

Logs:

```
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): Process: com.example.control, PID: 2052
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.control.MainActivity$RetriveTask$1
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.example.control.MainActivity$RetriveTask.onPreExecute(MainActivity.java:149)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.example.control.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:62)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
02-20 12:04:50.115: E/AndroidRuntime(2052):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: Do you expect us to generate codes from logcat?

Comment: post code what you tried to send email

Comment: I want to send email from android app in eclipse but I cannot resolve this error I tried every thing but it does not work i added three libraries additional, activation and javax.mail;

Comment: I posted the code below

Comment: What does this have to do with Eclipse?  Surely you are building the android app to run on an android device ... not in Eclipse.  (The fact that you are using Eclipse as your IDE is irrelevant to how you implement this ...)

Comment: the error almost refere to new javax.mail.Authenticator()

Comment: Try my answer, it is from working project.

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: `. Please comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

An Intent would be easiest way to do this, a little Googling doesnt hurt, honestly!

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"example@example.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body / text here");

//send
try {
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
    Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "There are no email clients installed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to collect your mail sender settings in a class like that:

```
public class GmailSender extends javax.mail.Authenticator {   
    private String mailhost = "smtp.gmail.com";   
    private String user;   
    private String password;   
    private Session session;   

    static {   
        Security.addProvider(new com.provider.JSSEProvider());   
    }  

    public GmailSender(String user, String password) {   
        this.user = user;   
        this.password = password;   

        Properties props = new Properties();   
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", user);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", mailhost);
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");  
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");

        session = Session.getInstance(props, this);    
    }   

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {   
        return new PasswordAuthentication(user, password);   
    }   

    public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {   
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);   
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));   
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));   
            message.setSubject(subject);   
            message.setDataHandler(handler);   
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)   
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));   
            else  
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));   
            Transport t = session.getTransport("smtp");
            t.connect(mailhost, user, password);
            t.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   

    public class ByteArrayDataSource implements DataSource {   
        private byte[] data;   
        private String type;   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data, String type) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public ByteArrayDataSource(byte[] data) {   
            super();   
            this.data = data;   
        }   

        public void setType(String type) {   
            this.type = type;   
        }   

        public String getContentType() {   
            if (type == null)   
                return "application/octet-stream";   
            else  
                return type;   
        }   

        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {   
            return new ByteArrayInputStream(data);   
        }   

        public String getName() {   
            return "ByteArrayDataSource";   
        }   

        public OutputStream getOutputStream() throws IOException {   
            throw new IOException("Not Supported");   
        }   
    }   
}
```

Use this class and send mail on your AsynchTask with that function:

```
private void sendMail()
{
    GmailSender sender = new GmailSender("yourMailAddress", "yourPassword");
    try {
        sender.sendMail("YourTitle",   
                "mailContent",   
                "fromMailAdress",   
                "toMailAdress");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

Call this method on `onDoingBackground()` method and here you go.

**Note:** Also be sure about that you have imported that javax libraries from Properties->Java Build Path

**Edit:** I forgot to add Provider class:

```
public final class JSSEProvider extends Provider {

    public JSSEProvider() {
        super("HarmonyJSSE", 1.0, "Harmony JSSE Provider");
        AccessController.doPrivileged(new java.security.PrivilegedAction<Void>() {
            public Void run() {
                put("SSLContext.TLS",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLContextImpl");
                put("Alg.Alias.SSLContext.TLSv1", "TLS");
                put("KeyManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.KeyManagerFactoryImpl");
                put("TrustManagerFactory.X509",
                    "org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerFactoryImpl");
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
            at com.example.montaser.test.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:51)